# How can I remove or change the icons from the listView field from the lightning-map?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-map

**Explaining my question:** I want to be able to remove, and-or change the green icons in the "listview" field. (circled in red) Would this be possible?

[image]

**My HTML Code:**

```
<template>
   
   <!-- Mapping. -->
   <lightning-map 

       map-markers={mapMarkers}
       zoom-level={zoomLevel}
       options={mapOptions}
       list-view={listView}
   
   >

   </lightning-map>

</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, this only appears to be possible by building the list view element of the map yourself. This would allow you to control the rendering of each of those elements.

If you were to do this, you'd also need to rebuild the interaction between the list view elements and the map itself. You can either wrap both the map and your list view in a parent component or use the [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel) use events from the list view/map to handle user interaction such as selecting a map marker.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the markers you can just supply any SLDS icon:

```
export default class LightningMapExample extends LightningElement {
    mapMarkers = [
        {
            location: {
                Street: 'The Landmark @ One Market, Suite 300',
            },
            title: 'The Landmark Building',
            icon: 'standard:account',
        },
    ];
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation